# Android push notification Urban AirShip error : invalid authorization on platform GCM

Tags: android, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I am using Urban Airship and my pushes are working fine on iOS but I have an error on Android.

In the error console on the urban airship website I have the message :

```
Received push with invalid authorization on platform GCM
```

My device is appearing in the section APIDs correctly and I verify all the steps in this address : https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/articles/823114-gcm-troubleshooting-guide.

This code show correctly an APID :

```
PushManager.shared().getAPID()
```

My properties seems to be good, I verified :

```
gcmSender = 123456789122
transport = gcm
developmentAppKey = APP KEY taken on the urban airship site
developmentAppSecret = APP KEY Secret taken on the urban airship site
inProduction = false
```

I also verified my GCM in the urban airship site, putting the correct Api key and Package from cloud.google.com.

Is there something I forgot?

Answer (score 2):

Few things you need to check here

1. Did u generate the key using Google Projects?
2. Once app starts, are you receiving unique registration id from Urban airship

Mostly point 2 is issue
also check if you are adding quotes to keys, if yes then add keys with no quotes

Comment: Thanks for your answer, first I have no quote anywhere, I understood it is not necessary. Should I put quote ? 1. My key was generate by google project yes. 2. Is there a code to test that ? I test only the PushManager.shared().getAPID() on my device, and it work

Comment: if you are getting value for getAPID() then everything is good from your side. Only problem I can see is from communication between your servers to Urban airship and Google servers. Check out this article https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/articles/823114-gcm-troubleshooting-guide . if you have already done this then you can contact UA helpdesk they respond quickly

Comment: Yeah I already tried that... Is there a possibility I did a mistake during the generating key part ? How can I be sure it is not an error from that part ?

Comment: You can generate the keys again. If you are using same projects for iOS and Android then there is large chance that you are mixing the keys

Answer (score 2):

I hope the below link will help you.

http://tuohuang.info/urbanairship-android-received-push-with-invalid-authorization-on-platform-gcm/#.U7KMrUCri41

Note: We should select the server key. If we choose any other for push notification,we will fall on this error.